# Javafx tableview get values from filtered list

Tags: javafx, tableview

Firstly I created table. And added values. Then added listener to textfield2 for search(filtering). And I have a getStatistics function for get total sum of values in one column. But it did not working after filtering datas. How can I get total sum of values after filtering?

```html
ObservableList<CurrentreservsController.userdata> data;
   data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
.......
.......

      FilteredList<userdata> filt = new FilteredList<>(data, p ->true);
                textfield2.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                filt.setPredicate(userdata -> {
                    if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                        return true;
                    }  
                    String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase(); 
               if (userdata.otag.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                        return true; // Filter matches first name.
                    } else if (userdata.cm.toString().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                        return true; // Filter matches last name.
                    }
                    return false; // Does not match.
                });
            });
             SortedList<userdata> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filt);
            sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tablesettings.comparatorProperty());
            tablesettings.setItems(sortedData);
             seartol=0; 
            getStatistics();
```

getStatistic function

```html
 private void getStatistics() {
          seartol=0; 
      for (userdata product : data) {
       seartol = seartol + Integer.parseInt(product.tol.getValue().toString());
       }
       label1.setText("Total sum: "+seartol);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to calculate your statistics based on the filtered list not the source list.

```
 private void getStatistics() {
     seartol=0; 
     for (userdata product : filt ) {
       seartol = seartol + Integer.parseInt(product.tol.getValue().toString());
     }
       label1.setText("Total sum: "+seartol);
 }
```

Comment: @Gpear: If a solution works for you, consider accepting it instead of just leaving a comment. This makes it easier for other to detect that a working solution has been found.